# Can't Access gnome-online-accounts

Tags: gnome, kde, google, google-drive

After installing KDE PLASMA, how do I use `gnome-control-center` and `online-accounts`?

I need to access my google drive from my Ubuntu 17.

When I open gnome-control-center it's just blank.

Comment: Why did you install "KDE PLASMA"? What was the exact command you used to do so? What is the output of `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`?